# Configuring joomshopping extension in joomla website

Tags: joomla

I am new to joomla. I am trying to configure the joomshopping shopping cart extension in my website. I installed it and added products. Now the real problem is i cannot figure out how to view the products page. Do i need to create an url seperately? or where can i find the product page url? Looking for some help immediately.

Comment: Create a menu item and assign the specific category (the category with your associated products) to that page.

Answer (score 0):

go to menu->main menu->new mwnu->joomshpoing->procuct->category_id
save and commit!